# Monte carlo on GPU

Tags: random, gpu, seed, montecarlo

Today I had a talk with a friend of mine told me he tries to make some monte carlo simulations using GPU. What was interesting he told me that he wanted to draw numbers randomly on different processors and assumed that there were uncorrelated. But **they were not**.

The question is, whether there exists a method to draw **independent** sets of numbers on several GPUs? He thought that taking a **different seed** for each of them would solve the problem, but it does not.

If any clarifications are need please let me know, I will ask him to provide more details.

Comment: How did you determine that they were uncorrelated?

Comment: It was not me, but as far as I understood he was calculating ordinary correlation between **random** numbers generated on **different** cores of a **GPU**. I am not much into how the random numbers are generated, so another question is what do "random" numbers depend on? Like cpu/gpu cycle or what?

Comment: He could have generated the random numbers from the hardware, or some software. Probably a pseudo-random generator where he is supplying a seed. He Could claim correlation, but he needs to demonstrate that the correlation is statistically different from 0, with a very large sample size.

Comment: But if for example the randomness of a number depends on the CPU. Then setting a different seed on each GPU will not help as it will only take another part of the same sequence - as far as I understand the idea of setting a seed.

Comment: He is probably setting a different seed on each just to insure that the sequences are not identical.

Answer (score 5):

To generate completely independent random numbers, you need to use a parallel random number generator. Essentially, you choose a single seed and it generates *M* independent random number streams.  So on each of the *M* GPUs you could then generate random numbers from independent streams.

When dealing with multiple GPUs you need to be aware that you want:

- independent streams within GPUs (if RNs are generate by each GPU)
- independent streams between GPUs.

It turns out that generating random numbers on each GPU core is tricky (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125148/using-random-numbers-with-gpus) I asked a while back). When I've been playing about with GPUs and RNs, you only get a speed-up generating random on the GPU if you generate large numbers at once.

Instead,  I would generate random numbers on the CPU, since:

- It's easier and sometimes quicker to generate them on the CPU and transfer across.
- You can use well tested parallel [random number generators](http://sprng.cs.fsu.edu/)
- The types of off-the shelf random number generators available for GPUs is very limited.
- Current GPU random number libraries only generate RNs from a small number of distributions.

---

To answer your question in the comments: What do random numbers depend on?

A very basic random number generator is the [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator). Although this generator has been surpassed by newer methods, it should give you an idea of how they work. Basically, the ith random number depends on the (i-1) random number. As you point out, if you run two streams long enough, they **will** overlap. The big problem is, you don't know when they will overlap.

Answer (score 3):

For generating *iid* uniform variables, you just have to initialize your generators with differents seeds. With Cuda, you may use the NVIDIA Curand Library which implements the Mersenne Twister generator.

For example, the following code executed by 100 kernels in parallel, will draw 10 sample of a (R^10)-uniform

```
__global__ void setup_kernel(curandState *state,int pseed)
{
    int id =  blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int seed = id%10+pseed;

    /* 10 differents seed for uncorrelated rv, 
    a different sequence number,    no offset */
    curand_init(seed, id, 0, &state[id]);
}
```

Comment: By "100 kernels in parallel," do you mean 100 threads in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

If you take any ``good'' generator (e.g. Mersenne Twister etc), two sequences with different random seeds will be uncorrelated, be it on GPU or CPU. Hence I'm not sure what you mean by saying taking different seeds on different GPUs were not enough. Would you elaborate?